# How to detect when the scroll starts using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to make a one pager website, without using any third party libraries, like FullPage.js.

- when scroll starts --> instead of waiting for the end of the natural scrolling, I want it to take no effect (so no visible scroll caused by the mouse) and to run my code instead. (so it could always go to next section, or previous one, without relying on the amount of the users scroll)

Do you have any idea how could I achieve this? My code snippet waits for the end of scroll, and then jumps to where it should, so it's not working as intended.

(the first section has a "current" class and then the code snippet works by manipulating the 100vh sections by adding/removing this class)

You can see the code snippet I am using below or here:
https://codepen.io/makiwara/pen/PoqjdNZ

Thank you very much for your help, have a nice day!

```
var script = document.createElement('script');script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
var timerId;
var scrollableElement = document.body; //document.getElementById('scrollableElement');

scrollableElement.addEventListener('wheel', checkScrollDirection);

function checkScrollDirection(event) {
    var $current = $('.current');
  if (checkScrollDirectionIsUp(event)) {
    console.log('UP');
$prev = $current.prev();

            if ($prev.length) {

                clearTimeout(timerId);
                timerId = setTimeout(function(){
                    $current.removeClass('current');
                    $prev.addClass('current');    
                    $('body,html').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top
                    }, 100);         
                }, 100) 
            }




  } else {
    console.log('Down');
$next = $current.next();

            if ($next.length) {
                clearTimeout(timerId);
                timerId = setTimeout(function(){
                    $current.removeClass('current');
                    $next.addClass('current');
                    $('body,html').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top
                    }, 100);         
               } , 100) 
            }

  }
}

function checkScrollDirectionIsUp(event) {
  if (event.wheelDelta) {
    return event.wheelDelta > 0;
  }
  return event.deltaY < 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is *throttling* the event listener, i.e. limit a function call only once per a time period.

What your code is doing is essentially *debouncing* i.e limit a function call only after a wait time period has passed.

Firstly ditch the timers you're using. You need to somehow block scrolling from happening more than once. The JavaScript part can be easy if you use [Underscore.js's throttle function](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) with one caveat though: It passes through subsequent events after the time period has passed. Luckily, its debouncing method accepts a third argument that gives the behavior you'd want:

```js
scrollableElement.addEventListener(
  "wheel",
  _.debounce(checkScrollDirection, 200, true) // immediately call the function _once_
);
```

This third argument makes the debounced function behave like a throttled one, that is it will fire *only once* and at the same time it will fire *immediately*.

So assuming that your event handler is now free from the original timeout

```js
function checkScrollDirection(event) {
  var $current = $(".current");
  if (checkScrollDirectionIsUp(event)) {
    console.log("UP");
    $prev = $current.prev("section");
    if ($prev.length) {
      $current.removeClass("current");
      $prev.addClass("current");
      $("body,html").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $prev.offset().top
        },
        100
      );
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Down");
    $next = $current.next("section");
    if ($next.length) {
      $current.removeClass("current");
      $next.addClass("current");
      $("body,html").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $next.offset().top
        },
        100
      );
    }
  }
}
```

btw, try to get into the habit of specifying selectors inside `.next()` and `.prev()` since jQuery will match *all possible* siblings, which most likely you don't want. In this case, codepen appends additional `<script>` elements and jQuery will match those as well.

Now if you try this, you'll notice that the window still responds to *every* scroll event. Scroll events are one of those events that cannot be cancelled so you need to disable it via CSS

The easiest way is to hide the overflow of the `body`

```css
body { max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; }
```

And that's it. You may need to adjust the throttle waiting time period to match your preferences.

You can find a working version of the codepen here: https://codepen.io/vassiliskrikonis/pen/XWbgxLj

Comment: Wow!!! You are great! Thank you very much for your help. It works like intended, just one little thing not. If I scroll a "bigger", it jumps often 2 or 3 sectons. Is there a way to only jump 1 section, no matter how big I scroll? Thank you very much, you made my day!

Comment: Hmm, check this version if it suits you more so I'll update my answer accordingly: https://codepen.io/vassiliskrikonis/pen/XWbgxLj

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! 
- works exactly when I change the position of the mouse and scroll at a new position
- however if I want to scroll through the page in one place, then it doesn't recognize the new scrolls, except if I click once.

It's almost there, just a very little is missing. Thank you very much for your help, you are teaching me a lot!

Comment: Weird, it works on my mac. Maybe you're not waiting long enough before scrolling? I've updated the codepen and you can see that actually the scroll events (depending of the input device) may continue firing for quite a while. To handle such cases, honestly you'd be better off with a specialized library.

Comment: Yes, that' correct! I haven't waited enough until the scroll event was over. So there is no easy way of stopping the scroll event once it has started? So we shouldn't wait until it's over, it's not very comfortable.

You helped me a lot and I am really sorry for my comment, you can skip this, if I ask too many questions, this is my last. I marked your answer as the solution, I am really grateful!

Comment: It's ok, that's what SO is for :). One thing I _would_ try first is to attach `wheel` event listeners only to the `.current` section (and make sure to re-attach the handlers on each section change). This way when the element scrolls out of view it will not trigger events. Or try to attach separate listeners for each section. Truth be told there's quite a lot of room to experiment from this point.